# iOS - How to Handle Existing Files on iCloud When Moving Files There (via setUbiquitous:)

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfilemanager

I am struggling to find the right approach to take when using `setUbiquitous:` to move local files to iCloud when the user has just enabled iCloud in my app. Trouble is, *this method fails when a document with the same name and path already exists on iCloud.*

So far I found that some advocate using a unique filename to perform the upload, but this doesn't sound right to me because it would mean that anyone who disables iCloud and then re-enables it in my app would have two versions of all their documents.

I also understand managing version conflicts AFTER files are in iCloud, but I can't use this here since calling `setUbiquitous:` must happen before any of that begins.

Please help me understand how to handle this. I couldn't find an answer to this in the iOS iCloud Design Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html) I appreciate any help!

Comment: So why don't you delete (or rename) the pre-existing iCloud file before moving the new file to iCloud?